# Writing Wav Files of Unknown Length (Java)

Tags: java, audio, wav

I am trying to add a feature to some audio processing software I have written.

My software already captures sound from a microphone input, processes it in real time, and sends the result to a speaker output.  (This is already a threaded application.)  I've been using javax.sound.sampled.* and working with wav data (transforming it to and from numerical samples to do the processing.

I would like to add a feature to save both the raw input and the transformed output of a session with this software to wav files.  But the signature for creating a new wav file (e.g., WavFile.newWavFile(...) seems to want to know in advance how many frames of data it is going to receive.  Since these are live sessions of indeterminate time, I have no way of knowing this information before hand.

Am I missing something?  Is there some way around this, other than a hack like saving files of data or samples, and then post-processing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most audio file writers need to know the full file size before writing to an output stream. There's an open source project called [Tritonus](http://tritonus.org/) which is an implementation of the Java sound API that has an AudioOutputStream plugin you could try.